# Renting camping equipment in Nambia

Tags: road-trips, camping, rental, namibia

I am planning a 3 week road trip in August in Namibia for 2 people. At first, I wanted to book a van or a 4x4 with a rooftop tent but it's quite expensive in August (more than 100$ a day).

As I saw in another [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/pros-and-cons-of-a-tent-on-the-ground-and-its-alternatives-in-namibia) it's OK to travel in Namibia with just a tent on the ground. So I am planning to rent a 2 WD car (Ford Focus or similar, 30$ a day) and then rent/buy camping equipment when I arrive in Windhoek.

Does this sound like a good option and where can I rent reliable camping equipment in Windhoek ?

Comment: "Nambia" in the title [is beautiful](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-41345577); please don't edit it. :-)

Comment: VTC: both opinion and shopping question.